# MapKit Swift Converting Address to Coordinated

Tags: swift, mapkit, geocoding

I have this function:

```
func addressToCoordinatesConverter(address: NSString) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if error = nil {
            if placemarks!.count = 0 {
                let annotation = MKAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = (placemark.location?.coordinate)!
                self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
                self.mapView.selectedAnnotations(annotation, animated: true)
            }
        }
    })
```

I call it in my code to convert an address (the string 'address') into coordinates and then onto my mapView. I am getting an error in the third line here saying

```
"NSString is not implicitly convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert"
```

How best can I fix this error? Thanks

Comment: as the error suggested. why dont u use String instead at the function? func addressToCoordinatesConverter(address: String)

Answer (score 1):

```
   func addressToCoordinatesConverter(address: String) {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if error = nil {
                if placemarks!.count = 0 {
                    let annotation = MKAnnotation()
                    annotation.coordinate = (placemark.location?.coordinate)!
                    self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
                    self.mapView.selectedAnnotations(annotation, animated: true)
                }
            }
        })
```

or

```
func addressToCoordinatesConverter(address: NSString) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address as! String, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if error = nil {
            if placemarks!.count = 0 {
                let annotation = MKAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = (placemark.location?.coordinate)!
                self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
                self.mapView.selectedAnnotations(annotation, animated: true)
            }
        }
    })
```

the first one you pass it a String, and the second an NSString. Use the one that is the same as what you want to pass in.